# Enable writing to file that is mapped to memory

Tags: c#, memory-mapped-files, memory-mapping

I will like to use a memory mapped file to virtualize opening a file on windows when that file is realy on the internet.

So I create the memory mapped file as:

```
// data that we write to the file. we will get this a tcp
var data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World");

var fileStream = new FileStream("SomeFile.txt", FileMode.Create);

using (MemoryMappedFile memoryMapped = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(fileStream, "MapName", 1024, 
    MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite, new MemoryMappedFileSecurity(), HandleInheritability.Inheritable, true))
{
    var viewStream = memoryMapped.CreateViewStream();                
    viewStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length); // write hello world                                
}
```

**And I can read from it on windows but not save it:**

[image]

Note how I was able to open the file (**meanwhile the data was on memory and not the hard disk**) but the moment I tried saving changes I was not able. **So my question is:** How could I enable saving changes to that file and be just changing the content in memory of the memory mapped file without actually trying to save anything to disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the sharing mode when creating the file stream.

```
var fileStream = 
    new FileStream("SomeFile.txt", FileMode.Create, 
                   FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

Also, you need to dispose of your FileStream when done, e.g. with a *using* statement.

**UPDATE**

It worked just fine for me.  Using Notepad I had to manually re-open the file, but I could update it while Notepad had it open (Notepad just did not check for external modifications).

Side note: The code writes a bunch of NUL (0x00) bytes to the end of the file.  You'll probably want to look into that.

Here's the exact code I used (note the local path to C:\Temp.  Change if needed):

```
    static private void WriteMMF()
    {
        // data that we write to the file. we will get this a tcp
        var data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World 2");

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Temp\SomeFile.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        using (MemoryMappedFile memoryMapped = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(fileStream, "MapName", 1024,
            MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite, new MemoryMappedFileSecurity(), HandleInheritability.Inheritable, true))
        {
            var viewStream = memoryMapped.CreateViewStream();
            viewStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length); // write hello world                                
        }
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Writing MMF");

        WriteMMF();

        Console.WriteLine("Done.  Press a key.");
        var ch = Console.ReadKey();

        return;
    }
```

Comment: +1 for helping thanks! I still where not able to save changes from windows explorer. I guess what am I asking is impossible right?

Comment: @TonoNam: Your screenshot shows Notepad.  Notepad may try to open the file in a manner that's not sharing friendly.  Try opening it in an editor like Notepad++, or just in Visual Studio.  Both play nicely with external updates.

Comment: Still not able to modify it from windows explorer. Maybe I will try to do a console.Read() instead of placing a breakpoint and see what happens!

Comment: Works for me.  Posted exact code that worked, along with the test scenario.

Comment: I don't want to write the data to disk. I was hoping to write the data to viewStream when saving the document...

Comment: So you want to go `File>Save` in notepad and have that change reflected in your loaded `MemoryMappedFile`?

Comment: if the file where to be on a network location notepad will not save it to disk so I was hopoing to do something similar. I think that is imposible right? Thanks for the help

Comment: Memory mapped files are real files, backed by a real file name.  They never exist only in memory.  Your application just accesses them using the same mechanism used for virtual memory swapping.